# PHP - Form fields that create MYSQL Queries on submit

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone help me with how can I achieve form fields that create MySQL queries? below are the details

Table name: `books`

| id | user_id | cateory_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | Book name 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | Book name 2 |

and in my HTML view this is how the form looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF5M1.jpg

The Column field drop down values are the table field names: `id, user_id, category_id, name`

The Comparison drop down values are: `'=', '<', '>', 'contains'`

`'contains'` value is like `'LIKE'` this must be change on the backend

and the Value input field is just a text field where you put what you are looking for

This form is dynamic where you can add filter with the radio button condition value of `'or'` or `'and'`

so my goal is when I click the submit button it will create mysql query with LEFT JOIN?I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do.

Sample output:

| id | user_id | cateory_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | Fiction | Book name 1 |
| 1 | John | Non-Fiction | Book name 2 |

below is my code to create mysql query but I think this is wrong because I have a `user_id` and `category_id` which I need to append the `JOIN`

```
$data = $request->getParsedBody();

$query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE ";

foreach ($data['column'] as $key => $value) {
    
    if ($data['comparison'][$key] == 'contains')
    {
        $data['comparison'][$key] = 'LIKE';
        $data['value'][$key] = "'%" . $data['value'][$key] . "%'";
    }
    if ($key <= 0)
    {
        $query .= "{$value} {$data['comparison'][$key]} '{$data['value'][$key]}'";
    }
    
    if ($key > 0) {
            if (!$value == "" && !$data['comparison'][$key] == "" && !$data['value'] == "")
        {
            $query .= " {$data['and_or'][$key-1]} {$value} {$data['comparison'][$key]} '{$data['value'][$key]}'";
        }
    }
}
$query .= " ORDER BY id DESC";
```

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Do you want to combine AND OR or will it be either `a AND b AND c AND d` or `a OR b OR c OR d` ? If you want to combine them how will a AND b OR c AND d be interpretered? `a AND ( b OR c AND d)` <> `(a AND b) OR (C AND D)`

Comment: I guess like this `a AND ( b OR c AND d)` @Kendle

Comment: does `a AND ( b OR c AND d)`therefore mean `a AND ( b OR c ) AND d` ie that the `OR`is evaluatied before the `AND` ?

Comment: Please provide a list of possible values in the dropdown, the definitions of the tables that the come from and the relationships between the tables

Comment: Hi @Kendle, the first dropdown menu (column) values are the field names of books (`id, user_id, category_id, name`)

Comment: and I have another two tables (`users and categories`) table. `books` table is related to these two table by the id

Answer (score 0):

As there are only 2 additional tablex we can hardcode them in the query, using a LEFT JOIN so that we will always get any matching data from books.
The following example uses one value for each possible search field. You could construct your query string dynamically using the same logic

```php
<?php

/* We are not prepared prepared to take any risks with sql injection */
if ("$data['comparison1'][$key]" == "AND") { andor[1] = AND } else { andor[1] = "OR"};
if ("$data['comparison2'][$key]" == "AND") { andor[2] = AND } else { andor[2] = "OR"};
if ("$data['comparison3'][$key]" == "AND" ){ andor[3] = AND } else { andor[3] = "OR"};

/* prepare the query using string concatenation with the the values in andor[] */
$query = "SELECT b.id, u.user_id, c.category_id, b.name 
FROM books b 
LEFT JOIN categories c ON b.id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN users u ON b.id = u.id
WHERE
( b.id = COALESCE(:book_id , b.id)"
.andor[1].
"( b.name = COALESCE(:book_name , b.name)"
.andor[2].
"( c.category_id = COALESCE(:category , c.category_id)"
.andor[3].
"( u.user_id = COALESCE(:user_id , u.user_id);";

/* Here you need to prepare the database connecter $dbh */
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'bookdb';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'S@cr@t1!';
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=UTF8";

/* and connect to the database */
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    if ($pdo) {
        echo "Connected to the $db database successfully!";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

/* we prepare the query and load the variables */
$sth = $pdo->prepare($query);
$sth->bindValue(':bookname', "$data['book_id'][$key]");  
$sth->bindValue(':book_name', "$data['book_name'][$key]");  ; 
$sth->bindValue(':category', "$data['category'][$key]");  
$sth->bindValue(':user_id', "$data['user_id'][$key]"); 

/* here we execute the query and extract the results*/
$sth->execute();
$book_results = $sth->fetchAll();

/* now you can exploit the table $book_results 
here we simply print it so that you can check */
print_r( $book_results);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Kendle. My problem is that some of the dropdown value are the relationship id from different table. how can I create query with LEFT JOIN?

Comment: let me give a try @Kendle